# How to stop after first constraint in springboot for validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, post

i have conrtoller advice:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
ResponseEntity<String> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException constraintViolationException) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(constraintViolationException.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

i have a controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="linkSellerBuyer")
@Validated
public String createSellerBuyer(Seller seller, Buyer buyer) {
    // some code
    return "some response";
}
```

each model are like:

```
public class Seller {
    @NotEmpty String Email;
    // and more and more
}

public class Buyer {
    @NotEmpty String Email;
    // and more and more
}
```

the error i get is i always get both seller and buyer errors

eg:
seller: must not be empty, buyer: must not be empty,

i want is
seller: must not be empty

?how can i create code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [check this out](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationInterceptor.java#L91) you will see that it validate all parameters at once.
But if you really want only one and first message you can extract it in your `handleConstraintViolationException`:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
ResponseEntity<String> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException constraintViolationException) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(constraintViolationException.getConstraintViolations()
            .iterator().next().getMessage(), 
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```